# Django virtual host setup. Apache mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, python-2.7, redhat

I am hoping there is a simple answer to my question as I am not the most experienced with python and Apache.

I am trying to hook up Apache with mod_wsgi. I have used a virtual host to do so. see below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName  testserver.com/django
#DocumentRoot /
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mycode/mysite/scripts/django.wsgi
Alias /media/ /home/mycode/mysite/mysite/media/
Alias /adminmedia/  /opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
<Directory "/home/mycode/mysite/mysite/media">
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works great for my django project when I go to testserver.com instead of my php index page I get my django project.

What I am looking for is help with allow my php projects in /var/www/html/ and my django projects to coexist. I am trying to make it so to reach my django project I type testserver.com/django

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mycode/mysite/scripts/django.wsgi
```

to:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /django /home/mycode/mysite/scripts/django.wsgi
```

The first argument is the mount point, you have it to be the root of the web server, so just change it to '/django' instead.