# Flask server not working on apache2 even though it works without it

Tags: python, apache, flask, apache2

The flask server was running perfectly fine but then I wanted to put it under apache server on ubuntu, however, for some reason, the wsgi script is not read and the web server url gives me `404 not found`.
I also realized that the WSGIScriptAlias is not recognized even though it doesn't show an error, because it's the only argument thats not colored in `vim`, so apparently the config file doesn't recognize it.

The packages installed are `apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 python-dev` and `a2enmod wsgi` enabled.

Here is the `flaskapp.wsgi`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                LoadModule wsgi_module     /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
                ServerName user-management
                ServerAdmin o.aa@example.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation/>
                        Allowoverride None
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation/static/>
                        AllowOverride None
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>

                Alias /templates /var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation/templates
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation/templates/>
                        AllowOverride None
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the `flaskapp.wsgi`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/customer-account-automation/")

from app import app as application
application.secret_key = 'secret'
```

This is the tree of the `/var` directory

```
└── www
    ├── FlaskApp
    │   ├── customer-account-automation
    │   │   ├── Pipfile
    │   │   ├── Pipfile.lock
    │   │   ├── README.md
    │   │   ├── app.py
    │   │   ├── customerAccountMgmt.py
    │   │   ├── get-pip.py
    │   │   ├── static
    │   │   │   ├── app.js
    │   │   │   ├── bulma.min.css
    │   │   │   ├── highlight.min.css
    │   │   │   ├── highlight.min.js
    │   │   │   └── styles.css
    │   │   └── templates
    │   │       ├── 404.html
    │   │       ├── base.html
    │   │       ├── change_password.html
    │   │       ├── create_user.html
    │   │       ├── deactivate_user.html
    │   │       └── login.html
    │   └── flaskapp.wsgi
    └── html
        └── index.html
```

Comment: Just to be sure, have you restarted your apache server? `sudo service apache2 restart` on ubuntu

Comment: yes indeed I did

Comment: As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081062/django-virtual-host-setup-apache-mod-wsgi have you also tried WSGIScriptAlias /FlaskApp /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi ?

Comment: didn't work out.

Comment: What about the error.log file? Do you mind posting the content if there's any?

Comment: its posted in the question

Comment: Sorry but I don't see it. Where should it be?